# Extract Content from Div Tag C# RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, html

I need to extract this content inside the divtestimonial1 div
I am using the following regEx, but its only returning the first line

```
Regex r = new Regex("&lt;div([^<]*<(?!/div>))");
```

```
  <div class="testimonial_content" id="divtestimonial1">
          <a name="T1"></a>
          <div class="testimonial_headline">%testimonial1headline</div>
          <p align="left"><img src="" alt="" width="193" height="204" align="left" hspace="10" id="img_T1"/><span class="testimonial_text">%testimonial1text</span><br />
          </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

[Regular expressions are generally not a good choice for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You might be better off using a tool such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), so I would suggest you use that.

That being said, you can match your particular sample input using this Regex:

```
<div.*?id="divtestimonial1".*?>.*</div>
```

But it might break in your real-world scenario. One of the troubles with Regex and HTML is properly detecting nesting of tags, etc.

Comment: And while that is generally true, what the OP asks here is quite practical and possible with RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be a good option using HtmlAgilityPack?

```
string input = "<div class=\"testimonial_content\" id=\"divtestimonial1\"><a name=\"T1\"></a><div class=\"testemonial_headline\">% testimonial1headline</div><p align=\"left\"><img src=\"\" alt=\"\" largura=\"193\" altura=\"204\" align=\"10\" id=/><br /></p></div>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(input);
HtmlNode divNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='divtestimonial1']");
if (divNode != null)
{
    string content = divNode.InnerHtml;
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

result:

```
<a name="T1"></a><div class="testemonial_headline">% testimonial1headline</div><p align="left"><img src="" alt="" largura="193" altura="204" align="10" id=/><br></p>
```

Using Regex.Match it would look like this:

```
string input = "<div class=\"testimonial_content\" id=\"divtestimonial1\"><a name=\"T1\"></a><div class=\"testemonial_headline\">% testimonial1headline</div><p align=\"left\"><img src=\"\" alt=\"\" largura=\"193\" altura=\"204\" align=\"10\" id=/><br /></p></div>";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "<div class=\"testimonial_content\" id=\"divtestimonial1\">(?<content>.*?)</div>");
if (match.Success)
{
    string content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```