# Get Div Content with Regular Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex, text, html

i have this Html code:

```
<div id="top" style="something i dont know">
Text
</div>
```

And i only want to get the string "Text".
My script looks like this:

```
Regex search_string = new Regex("<div id=\"top\".*?>([^<]+)</div>");
Match match = search_string.Match(code);
string section = match.Groups[0].Value;
MessageBox.Show(section);
```

Is this even possible with C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Content from Div Tag C# RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775265/extract-content-from-div-tag-c-regex)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775265/extract-content-from-div-tag-c-regex, among many others.

Answer (score 0):

use XPath its much easier

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

use this as xpath selector

```
//div[@id='top']
```

then u can get inner value

Answer (score 0):

You should better use XPath as mentioned before. To be able to work with HTML as with XML you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is very useful for tasks like yours.