# C# Regular Expression Help Needed

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)
> [Extract Content from Div Tag C# RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775265/extract-content-from-div-tag-c-sharp-regex)

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Question

How do I write a regular expression (in C#) to reduce this string:

```
<span class='foo'>bar</span>
```

To this:

```
bar
```

In a severe time crisis, so please excuse my not R*ing*TFM!  Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Do you want a regular expression for that exact string (if so why) or a class of strings which that is an example of? replacing `.*` with `bar` will satisfy your requirements but I am sure the requirements are stronger than that so you should try to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Especially when you're in "a a severe time crisis" you should take the time to detail the question correctly. The current one is answerable with `return "bar";`

Comment: Thanks for all of your concern fellas, but Joey answered the question with just what I needed within seconds of posting and without further detail.  That guy must be really smart.  Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "<[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: Claro!  Thank you sir!  I can accept in 12 minutes. . .

Comment: Fits the job description, will however fail if the input string is not exactly <openingTag>string</closingTag>

Comment: Apparently it suffices (see other comment). Most questions of that form aim at removing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags/787951#787951).

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

But notice [these warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787951/608457).

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the same result with:

```
XDocument.Parse("<span class='foo'>bar</span>").Element("span").Value
```

Comment: Provided it's valid XML which usually can't be said of HTML.

Comment: xhtml isn't very common? (i'm asking, i don't know)

Comment: To my knowledge it's not that common on the web.